# Building a webservice in Azure ML Studio to return similar records from a training dataset

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio, azure-ml-pipelines

I've searched high and low for an example of how to build an inference pipeline in Azure ML that will return records most similar to an entity passed in a Web Service Input.

My dataset consists of a set of features extracted using "Extract N-Gram Features from Text" which is then trained using a Multiclass Logistic Regression model. I think the answer lies in using a Cosine Similarity model but I can't find how to do this in ML Studio. I'm happy to jump into R, but I just need a good example to get started with. My searches are turning up nothing that seems to be close to what I'm trying to achieve. Starting to suspect I'm searching for the wrong thing! Would be really grateful if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Here's what my source data looks like:

| Project | Technology | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | Tech1 Tech2 Tech5 | Cat1 |
| Project2 | Tech1 Tech4 Tech6 | Cat2 |
| Project3 | Tech2 Tech4 Tech7 | Cat3 |

Then my input data will be:

| Technology | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Tech1 Tech3 Tech5 | Cat1 |

And the Web Service might return:

Closest match: Project1